# Select Dinamico

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hola muy buen día quien me puede orientar un poco

Quiero hacer un select que cuando en ese select seleccione Articulo=10001 automáticamente me haga la consulta 1 y 2 pero que el resultado me lo muestre así txt1= consulta 1 y txt2=consulta2

EJEMPLO

BD

| ID | ARTICULO | TIPO | IMPORTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | ADMI | 100 |
| 2 | 10000 | OPE | 60 |
| 3 | 10000 | OPE | 120 |
| 4 | 10001 | ADMI | 150 |

CONSULTA 1

```
SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10001',importe,0)) Suma1
FROM gastos
WHERE tipo='ADMI';
```

CONSULTA 2

```
SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10000',importe,0)) Suma2
FROM gastos
WHERE tipo='OPE';
```

EJEMPLO HTML

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <select  style="width:230px">
    <option>Selecciona Articulo</option>
    <?php
    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM bd ORDER BY ARTICULO DESC");
    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$valores[ARTICULO].'">'.$valores[ARTICULO].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <td><table><B>suma1</B></table></td>
    <td><table><B>suma2</B></table></td>
    <td><table><B>suma3</B></table></td>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Es como para hacer un concentrado general
Ya llevo un buen rato batallando en esta función :(
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo que tendrías que hacer es usar la funcion onchange en tu select lo cual quedaria haci

```
<select  style="width:230px" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
```

Luego dentro de myFunction() realizar una peticion ajax, aqui podras validar si se ejecuta o no la petición ajax desacuerdo al valor que selecciones

```
function myFunction(val) {
if(val == 10001){
 $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
        success: function (response) {

           // You will get response from your PHP page (what you echo or print)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

la url es el archivo donde están tus consultas, el resultado de esas consultas se lo devuelves en un array de objetos a la petición Ajax si todo sale bien el resultado estara el la variable response 'success: function (response) {' ya con todo esto podrás recorrer el array y mostrar los valores donde quieras (input, label etc)

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirvió mucho